# Hide ribbon button in site actions is grayed out in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

In my SP2013 environment, when I visit my page as site collection admin, I want to see the page with the ribbon hidden. However when I click the site actions button, the hide ribbon button is grayed out. How can I enable it?

Thanks

Comment: What is the template used for the site collection you're seeing this on? For instance, if you chose publishing, this doesn't allow itself to be disabled through the UI. You'll need to use CSS. Chose the blank template, and the option can be chosen.